# Как точно определить есть ли какие-то значения в массиве?

Tags: php, массивы, if

Не знаю, может глупый вопрос, но пока не нашел эффективного решения, поэтому обращаюсь к профессиональному сообществу.
Есть многомерный динамический массив, типа:

```
 $array = array(
          'one' => array(
                  'one_one' => array(
                              'one_one_one' => 'hello'
                               ),
                  'one_two' => array(
                              'one_two_one' => 'world'
                               )
                    ),
          'two' => 'hello world'
           );
```

Если проверять стандартными проверками типа if($array); if(count($array)); if(!empty($array)); if(count($array, 1)); то если присутствует хоть один ключ, даже пустой, то выражение считается истинным.

Вопрос как узнать есть ли хоть какое-то значение в массиве или нет. То есть, если будет массив вида:

```
 $array = array(
          'one' => array(
                         'one_one' => ''
                   )
           );
```

То результат должен быть false.

Спасибо!

Comment: Насколько большой может быть вложенность массивов?

Comment: `array_walk_recursive()` ?

Comment: @Дмитрий Не знаю как это сказать по-научному, но в первоначальном массиве $array может быть до 4х вложенных.

Comment: @klopp, приблизительно такой вариант сейчас в работе, но по сравнению с этой функцией велосипедный. Если не найду чего-то по-лучше, придется использовать это решение.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128323/in-array-and-multidimensional-array

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, там обсуждается вопрос поиска определенного значения в массиве. У меня вопрос другой.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо обходить все элементы массива, пока не найдётся непустое значение. Проверку на пустоту пересмотрите, `empty` для примера.

```
$found = FALSE;
try{
    array_walk_recursive(
        $array,
        function( $value, $index) {
            if( !empty( $value)) throw( new Exception('found: ' . $value));
        }
    );
} catch( Exception $e) {
    $found = TRUE;
}
printf( "%s\n", $found ? "Есть значения" : "Пустой");
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/NdS0B0)

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает отлично и намного элегантнее моего решения.

Answer (score 1):

Я не особо представляю, в каком виде тебе нужны результаты, поэтому примерно

```
function search_in_array($arr, $nam="_parent"){
     $result = false;
     foreach($arr as $k => $v){
         if(is_array($v)){//Если это дочерний массив - то применяем к нему ту же ф-цию,что и к родительскму
             $tmp = search_in_array($v, $nam.'->'.$k); 
             $result = ($result == true)? $result : $tmp; //Это чтобы не сбить ранее полученное положительное значение обратно на отрицательное
         }else if(!empty($v)){$result = true;}
     }
     echo 'Массив '.$nam.' '.($result ? 'заполнен' : 'пуст').'<br>';
      return $result;//Для получения $tmp для родительского массива (см. выше)
     }      

  search_in_array($array);
```

В принципе, можно еще добавить is_object() к is_array(), чтобы еще и объекты сканировал. В данном примере результаты просто выводятся на экран, т.к. я незнаю, что ты с этими результатами хотел сделать. В принципе, их можно в массив глобальный совать, или удалять пустышки таким образом или еще что-то - тебе виднее

Comment: Мне на самом деле просто проверка нужна была - есть что-то в массиве или нет. ИМХО решение немного выше более читабельное, а то, какое привели Вы, как раз у меня и стояло, немного в другом виде. 
Правда я думал может есть стандартная функция для этого.